# Why does NexusIQ Server still shows the exlude library as a finding after Re-Evaluate Report?

Tags: java, soap, dependencies, pom.xml, nexus-iq

After finding "soap : soap : 2.3.1" as security critical in NexusIQ Server, I decided to exclude the dependency from pom.xml because "soap" was used as a transitive dependency and the project did not use it.
I can still see a critical finding for it in NexusIQ Server. Does anyone know why?

Tried to exlude the dependency: